# Power of sums inequality

Tags: analysis

I'm reading an article and the author says that this inequality is elementar

$\left|\left|\displaystyle\sum_{j=1}^l z_j \right|^p-\displaystyle\sum_{j=1}^l |z_j|^p\right|\leq C_l \sum_{j\neq i} |z_i||z_j|^{p-1},\quad p\in(1,\infty).$

Where $z_j\in\mathbb{R}$ and $C_l$ is a constant that depends on $l$. For $p\in\mathbb{Z}$ I can see why this is true using newton binomial and majoring the mix terms. But, i don't have idea how to prove when p is real, can anyone help me?

Comment: What article? What are the $z_j$? What is $C_l$?

Comment: z_j are real numbers, C_l is a constant that depends on l

Comment: You've told us $p\in\Bbb Z$ and $p\in(1,\infty)$ - care to say which is right? You'll maybe make use of the approach: show using calculus that: $$\frac{\left|\sum_{j=1}^lz_j\right|^p-\sum_{j=1}^l|z_j|^p}{\sum_{j\neq i}|z_i||z_j|^{p-1}}$$Is bounded

Comment: It is worthwhile observing that $$\sum_{i\neq j}|z_i|\,|z_j|^{p-1}=\left (\sum |z_i|\right )\, \left (\sum |z_i|^{p-1}\right )-\sum |z_i|^p$$